# Why is this error occuring only when building the docker image

Tags: laravel, docker, composer-php

I have updated my Laravel app from 6 to 7 and then 8 without problems. However, when I try to build an my docker image, it fails at the `composer install --no-dev -o` command. If I run the same command in my terminal, there is no error.
The error is

```
In Request.php line 335:
                                                                               
  Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create() mus  
  t be of the type string, null given, called in /app/vendor/laravel/framewor  
  k/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/SetRequestForConsole.php on line 32
```

and the command used to build the image is `@docker build $(DOCKER_BUILD_ARG)  -t $(IMAGE_TAG)  -f $(DOCKERFILE) .`
It seems like it is a problem with a laravel framework file. I Googled this error but have not found any solution. I tried to run composer dump autoload, php artisan cache:clar and php artisan config:clear, none of these fixed my issue.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM armcanada/php7-mssql:latest

# Copy files
ADD . /app/
ADD php.ini /etc/php.ini
ADD arm-http.conf /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/arm-http.conf

# Install app dependencies
RUN composer install --no-dev -o

# Fix permissions
RUN chmod -R 777 ./storage
RUN chmod -R 777 ./bootstrap/cache

# Cache route & views
RUN php artisan route:cache
RUN php artisan view:cache

CMD ["start_httpd"]
```

and my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.3.0",
        "armcanada/laravel-honeypot": "dev-master",
        "bacon/bacon-qr-code": "^2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
        "box/spout": "^3.0.1",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.7",
        "erusev/parsedown": "^1.7",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "hackzilla/password-generator": "^1.5",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^4.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "paragonie/constant_time_encoding": "^2.3",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "rickycezar/laravel-jwt-impersonate": "^1.3",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.18",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mz\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Support/Helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/armcanada/laravel-honeypot"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "tymon/jwt-auth"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why I am getting downvoted for this. I Also tried to remove the vendor folder and the composer.lock file, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it by editing the `app/config.php` file.
The error was that the `url` key was null so I added a default value to the `env()` function:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'default'),
```

Comment: This worked for me. Adding the `APP_URL` on the .env would have worked too (my local .env file didn't have that variable).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error when I had the `.env` file in before running composer install then it worked fine