# Laravel Beanstack unable to run artisan commands in beanstalk - Request::create() must be of the type string, null given

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to run artisan command in my beanstalk setup, but keep getting this error.

[image]

```sh
In Request.php line 334:
                                                                                                                                                             
  Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/app/current/vendor/laravel  
  /framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/SetRequestForConsole.php on line 32
```

My application is working fine but when I try to run any command the following error keeps on popping up. I was trying to set supervisor tool to run my queues. But it's status is keeps on saying fatal error.

[image]

And it has the same error in its log file. Looking at the error it seems that there is some issue with console commands.

env key for `APP_URL` is properly set and verified.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Argument one is `$url` which [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/SetRequestForConsole.php#L18) comes from `config('app.url')`. Might indicate your .env file is not being read. Try setting the `app.url` config variable directly to see if that works

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268632/why-is-this-error-occuring-only-when-building-the-docker-image) worked for me.